# How can I create a mid-measure key-signature in Finale?

Tags: key-signatures, finale

I have a key-signature half-way a measure. I discovered clef change mid-measure, but not key-signatures. Is that possible?

Comment: Why would you need a key change half-way through a bar? It's pretty well unheard of. You could use accidentals instead.

Comment: I think I've seen some classical music with mid-measure key signature changes. Faithfully copying them with music notation software pretty much requires this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s no straightforward way to do this, but there is a way that isn’t too hard. Use two measures, each with a time signature that is half of a measure. Check the box for a different display signature that matches the time signature you actually want. For example, if the piece is in 4/4, make two measures that are 2/4 but are set to display as if they were 4/4.

Now, put the key change in the second measure. You can then choose either to make the right bar line of the first half-measure into a dashed bar line (my recommendation) or make it completely invisible. A similar trick can be used for lots of unconventional mid measure stuff.

There may be a few adjustments you’ll have to make. Bear in mind that Finale will always consider this measure to be two measures, so you’ll need to adjust measure numbers after it (this is easy, just uncheck the box in the measure properties for the second measure that includes it in the numbering), and you might need to force or unforce some accidentals in the second half measure. You’ll also probably have to be careful about any line breaks in the score and parts, since you probably don’t want the two half-measures to be separated from each other.

Comment: Please explain why any of this might be necessary.

Comment: @Tim Because I’m fairly certain that Finale doesn’t have a simple, built-in way to do what the OP wants. I could be wrong, do you know another way?

Comment: Not at all. I just don't understand why a piece needs to change key in the middle of a bar.

Comment: To avoid the unsightly clutter of accidentals that would ensue if the change were deferred to the next barline.

Comment: @RosieF, wouldn't that unsightly clutter of accidentals happen mid-bar, then? Except that Finale has all kinds of "overrides" that one can do to all sorts of features, for example eliminate key signature change warning signs. Finale has all sorts of tricks, but they are too hard to explain here because they are so specific and not common, I have to look them up every time I do it. Go into Finale help and search the user guide and read the directions. It can be a little challenging to really get to know how to use Finale's more hidden features, but very worth it.

Comment: I was thinking of the accidentals on those notes that come after the mid-bar place where the OP wanted to change key sig, but before the end of the bar, and which don't match with the old sig.

Comment: @Tim, Because I have a key signature change mid-measure. A mid-measure change keeps the time-signatures the same, else I have to change the time signatures. I am not too keen for that.

Comment: And more of an explanation, the piece uses many modulations. I will be more clear to the performer that the modulation is where it belongs in the piece instead of artificial meter changes (I do know) or confusing accidentals (I abolished).

Answer (score 0):

You want A rather than B?  Yes, think in terms of splitting the bar into two rather than inserting a key signature mid-bar.

My example was done in Sibelius, but the same can be achieved easily in Finale.

[image]